# Aggregate Pandas Column based on values in Column Range

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Dataset:

[image]

Need output like below in using dataframe pandas. I would like to group by PRCP based on the PRCP range and aggregate the count. Please advise

[image]

Comment: Use the `cut` function to divide PRCP into bins and group by the bins: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'CLDATE':['1/1/16','1/10/16','1/11/16','11/12/16','11/13/16','11/14/16','11/15/16','11/16/16'],
                   'count':[64396,49877,41603,41124,45839,45846,52719,59626],'PRCP':[0,1.8,0,0,0,0,0,0.24]})


df['precipate_Range']=pd.cut(df['PRCP'],[0,1,2,3],right=False,labels=['0-1','1-2','2-3'])

df.groupby('precipate_Range')['count'].agg({'Sum':'sum'}).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
  precipate_Range       Sum
0             0-1  351153.0
1             1-2   49877.0
2             2-3       NaN
```